# jQuery Simulate Mouse Actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, leap-motion

I want to create an interface for an input device in Javascript and I want to be able to use all of JQuery and JQuery UI's native events and functions (such as mouseover, mouseenter, mousedown, Draggable, etc.) without using the actual mouse (I will provide the x, y coordinates and whether the input device is clicked or not). How do you think I could achieve that?

Example : Integrating Leap Motion API with JQuery where after getting the x, y coordinates from the Leap Motion API, I pass it as a "simulated mouse" to the JQuery API and therefore I would be able to drag and drop, click and hover on items in the webpage using the Leap Motion instead of the mouse.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: would something like this be helpful? https://github.com/miya0001/jquery-leapmotion

Comment: I would advise looking at jQuery Mobile. Not saying to use it, but examine how it handles the gap between touch events to virtual mouse events. A tap to align with click event, for example. depending on what you're doing or using it with, you could simple use the jQuery Mobile along with UI.

Comment: @abigwonderful not really, I am looking to use the native events (on "mousedown", "mouseup", "mouseover", etc.) Twisty : So basically I'll have to trigger the events one by one?